# Data sharing between ReactJs/Node app an Flutter mobile app

Tags: reactjs, flutter

Please, I'm planning to design a Web App with **ReactJs/Node** then its mobile version with **Flutter**.
From your experiences, can you advise me **a way of data sharing between these stacks**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to create REST or GraphQL API using nodeJS so that you can access it both from the React and Flutter app.

[Creating a Secure REST API in Node.js](https://www.toptal.com/nodejs/secure-rest-api-in-nodejs)

[Creating A GraphQL Server With Node.js And Express](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/creating-a-graphql-server-with-node-js-and-express-f6dddc5320e1)

Comment: ok, thanks a lot @Besufkad for the response and the links provided.

Comment: I will follow them and won't hesitate to reach out to you whenever needed. Thanks again

Comment: anytime bro. Good Luck!